# What about SE site links in tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

So I have declared war on the un-defined tags to give the site more help and help people understand what questions are suppose to be about. Since we have off-topic questions I have been including a link to another related SE to show users a possible place for off-topic questions. My tag looks like this from [Garden tag](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tags/garden/info):

> This tag is for hacks related to a area of land used to cultivate
>   fruits or vegetables. The question would have to be looking for a
>   alternative method and name methods already used.
>
> For Gardening Questions off-topic, see the [Gardening & Landscaping
>   Stack Exchange](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tags/garden/info).

My question is does this method:

- Make people more likely to leave this site and go to another site?
- Does this discourage users?
- Does it add something and should be rephrased? Or should it just be scrapped?

***All input is needed and welcome and will be taken into account since this is every users community.***

Comment: +1 for the exceptional job rounding out the definitions.. I have "reviewed" about 40 of them in the last few days.

Answer (score 5):

I think including links to relevant Stack Exchange sites are great... especially when helping new users stay on-topic. I think it is better to refer a user to another SE site than to let them post something here that gets closed.

Here are a few examples: [[javascript] on Super User](https://superuser.com/tags/javascript/info), [[photoshop] on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/photoshop/info), [[android] on Super User](https://superuser.com/tags/android/info), [[osx] on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/osx/info)... the list goes on.

Here's what [I put](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/revisions/523/4) in [food](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food):

> For cooking related questions that are *not* on-topic here, see [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) -- another Q&A site in the Stack Exchange network.

Put simply, **Only recommend the site if the Q is OT here.**

Comment: But what are your opinions on this making people stray from the site?

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock I added an example that I edited into [tag:food]. **Only recommend the site if the Q is OT here.**

Comment: This works thanks. I wanted more detail, but this is fine as it is.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a good idea to point people to other SE sites where they can get answers to questions that are offtopic on this one.

I can't recall any specific examples right now, but i think i've seen it elsewhere as well.

EDIT: See [[Hebrew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/hebrew/info)] on Mi Yodeya.